# How to setup apache with 2 laravel project

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, apache2

first I copy 000-default.conf

cp 000-default.conf demo

then I link demo in site-avaible

```
ln -s ../sites-available/demo demo
```

here is my `000-default.conf` I want to set project run in www.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias demo.example.com/
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combin
    </VirtualHost>
```

here is my demo file I want to project run in demo.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/main/public
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 <Directory /var/www/html/main/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after that I run service apache2 restart I can enter in www.example.com only but I cant enter to demo.example.com . I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few minor things I feel the need to say -  First, I would always leave `.conf` on copied files. Second, I would always use `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` to enable and disable any sites.

I would also disable the default site in this case if you are using the `example.com` domain name. If your default site is not currently enabled, that would be why you can't access `demo.example.com` - if you're looking to access that site, you'll need to enable it by running `a2ensite 000-default`